# Crystal Reports: Shift other cells down to avoid overlap

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

I have a field that can grow vertically and potentially overlap other fields. Is there a way to avoid this overlap? I I wan't all the data to show, I'd like for the other fields to be shifted down as the cell grows. I haven't found something similar online as of yet.

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the report but you could potentially create a text box and drop the fields you need in the text box with a carriage return after each.

Comment: @CoSpringsGuy, Just to keep it simple, I have a single field I'm getting from the DB and a text box right under it. I want the text box to be shifted down when the DB field box grows too tall so that they don't overlap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered my own question. Place everything that might overlap in one text box and then format accordingly.